# Get rid of trailing \x00 on a bytearray

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I am trying to transmit a matrix from a transmitter to receiver serially. To do that I am trying to read each row of a matrix, turn it into a bytearray for transmission, then decode it in the reciever. So far when I am turning each row into a bytearray, each number gets trailed by null elements.

```
a = np.random.randint(0,255,size=(20,20))
print(a)


for row in a:
    b = bytearray(row)
    print(b)
```

lets say the array from on of the rows was [1,2,3,4]

expected outcome: 
     `bytearray(b'\x01\x02\x03\x04')`

but the outcome I get is:
     `bytearray(b'\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00...')`

My receiver uses list() to decode the message so an array with [1,2,3,4] will become [1,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,4,0,0,0] to the receiver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.random.randint.html):

> dtype : dtype, optional
>
> Desired dtype of the result. All dtypes are determined by their name, i.e., ‘int64’, ‘int’, etc, so byteorder is not available and a specific precision may have different C types depending on the platform. The default value is ‘np.int’.
>
> New in version 1.11.0.

(`dtype` is short for `data type`, and is a parameter for a large number of Numpy functions.)

Unless you specify otherwise, `np.random.randint` gives you `np.int`-sized values, which take up four bytes of space. (It does not matter that single bytes would suffice for the random range you specified.)

To fix this, specify the [appropriate](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html) dtype:

```
a = np.random.randint(0, 255, size=(20,20), dtype=np.uint8)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've got "a" as an array of integers, and each one of those is actually stored in 4 bytes -- because integers can hold much larger values than 255, the maximum value held by an unsigned byte. So those sets of 3 zeroes in between each of the values you care about are "the rest of the integer".

I can't remember if np.random provides a way to initialize it as an array of bytes. Or you could have an intermediate step where you copy every 4th byte from your "row" into a new byte array "c" before you transmit it.

Anyway hopefully that at least points you in the right direction.